# P-value correction when evaluating correlation between gene and miRNA expression

Tags: statistics, gene-expression, correlation, p-values

First of all I apologize without the question is very basic, I am taking my first steps in bioinformatics.

### Data information

We are evaluating the correlation (using the Pearson, Kendall or Spearman method) between gene expression and miRNA expression using the [corAndPvalue](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WGCNA/versions/1.69/topics/corAndPvalue) function of WCGNA.

The resulting structure would be a DataFrame containing all combinations between each gene with each miRNAs, containing the following columns:

```
Gene     miRNA      Correlation P-value
Gen_1    miRNA_1    0,959       0.00311
Gen_1    miRNA_2    -0,039      0.1041
Gen_1    miRNA_3    -0,344      0.0021
Gen_2    miRNA_1    0,1333      0.00451
Gen_2    miRNA_2    0,877       0.07311
...
```

### Question

Considering the huge number of correlation tests we are going to evaluate, we need to adjust the p-values to avoid correlations due to chance. Bonferroni does not seem to be the best solution, so we would use Benjamini-Hochberg method (BH). The question is:

The BH correction for the `Gen_1` x `miRNA_1` combination, should consider the p-values of all combinations that include Gen_1 (Option 1), or should consider all the p-values of all the genes x miRNA combinations (Option 2)?

For example, let's assume an expression dataset of 20,000 genes and another of 15,000 miRNAs

**Option 1:**

To adjust `Gen_1` x `miRNA_1` we would use 15,000 p-values (`Gen_1` x `miRNA_1`, `Gen_1` x `miRNA_2`, ..., `Gen_1` x `miRNA_15000`).

**Option 2:**

To adjust `Gen_1` x `miRNA_1` we would use 300,000,000 p-values (`Gen_1` x `miRNA_1`, `Gen_1` x `miRNA_2`, ..., `Gen_1` x `miRNA_15000`, `Gen_2` x `miRNA_1`, `Gen_2` x `miRNA_2`, ..., `Gen_2` x `miRNA_15000` and so on).

### Suplementary question

Documentation of the method [fdrcorrection](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.multitest.fdrcorrection.html?highlight=fdrcorrection#statsmodels.stats.multitest.fdrcorrection) from Python [Statsmodels library](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) suggests that for negative correlations (that could be frequent in a mRNA x miRNA correlation analysis) Benjamini-Yekutieli would work better; is that right? Or Benjamini-Hochberg method would be appropiated for this case?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a good answer in CrossValidated forum! [Link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478037/p-value-correction-for-multiple-testing-using-huge-datasets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the same [question in CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478037/208550) forum and got an excellent answer!

The important part:

> You need to correct for all of the comparisons you are doing. So if
> that's 300,000,000 comparisons you need to correct for that many
> multiple comparisons.

For more information check the answer in the link above